# How to sum a mongodb inner field and push it during grouping using MongoTemplate

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

I can use the sum within the push operation in a MongoDB console. However, I am not getting how can I do the same using MongoTemplate?

```
$group : {
     _id: "$some_id",
     my_field: { $push : {$sum: "$my_field" }}
 }
```

The code I am using for this is something like:

```
Aggregation aggregation =
    Aggregation.newAggregation(
        match(matchingCriteria),
        group("some_id")
            .count()
            .as("count")
            .push("my_field")
            .as("my_field")
        project("some_id", "count", "my_field"));
AggregationResults<MyModel> result =
    mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "my_collection", MyModel.class);
```

The thing is I want the sum of **my_field** but it is coming as an array of **my_field** here(as I am directly using the push). I am able to achieve the same using the above sum inside of push operation. But not able to use that for MongoTemplate. My app is in Spring Boot. I have also looked into the docs for these methods but couldn't find much.

Also, I tried directly using .sum() as well on the field(without using the push), but that is not working for me as my_field is an inner object, and it's not a number but an array of numbers after the grouping. That is why I need to use the push and sum combination.

Any help regarding this is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using the below code:

```
Aggregation aggregation =
    Aggregation.newAggregation(
        match(allTestMatchingCriteria),
        project("some_id")
            .and(AccumulatorOperators.Sum.sumOf("my_field"))
            .as("my_field_sum")
        group("some_id")
            .count()
            .as("count")
            .push("my_field_sum")
            .as("my_field_sum"),
        project("some_id", "count", "my_field_sum"));
AggregationResults<MyModel> result =
    mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "my_collection", MyModel.class);
```

I used [AccumulatorOperators.Sum](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/AccumulatorOperators.Sum.html) in the projection stage itself and sum the inner fields and get the desired output. Then I passed this to the grouping stage where I did the count aggregation as I needed that data as well and then had to project all the data generated to be collected as output.